# How display Last modified in profile wordpress

Tags: profiles

this code not display right date of profile modified ... 
 this code not display right date of profile modified ... 
 this code not display right date of profile modified ... 
 this code not display right date of profile modified ... 
 this code not display right date of profile modified ... 
 this code not display right date of profile modified ... 
 this code not display right date of profile modified ... 
 this code not display right date of profile modified ...

Comment: sorry <?php  echo  get_the_modified_date();   ?> this code not display right date of profile modified ...